# How to search enter the edittext value from database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-edittext

I want the Validation for the mobile number ,Am enter the edit text value search with database i want get the error already register your number for the validation setError Or Toast message,Add the Main class, Model class and AppUtil class kindly help me , Am attached code given below. Please tell what i set validation.

```
public class CreateRyotManagerFragment extends Fragment {
EditText mRyotName, mRyotFatherName, mAddress, mIdNo, mMobile1;
Spinner mDivision;
List<RyotMasterDb> mRyotList;
List<DivitionMasterDb> mDistrickarray;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_new_ryot, container, false);

    mMobile1 = view.findViewById(R.id.mobile);
    mDivision = view.findViewById(R.id.divition);
    mRyotList = AppUtils.getRyotMasterList();
    mDistrickarray = AppUtils.getDistrictMasterLIst();

    SpinnerAfdapterDistric divisionAdapter = new SpinnerAfdapterDistric(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mDistrickarray);
    mDivision.setAdapter(divisionAdapter);

}
```

}

```
@Table(name = "ryotMasterDB", database = AppDatabase.class)
RyotMasterDb extends Model implements Serializable {
@PrimaryKey
public Long id;

@Column(name = "mobile_1")
public String mobile_1;
@Column(name = "mobile_2")
public String mobile_2;
@Column(name = "zone_group_id")
public String zone_group_id;
@Column(name = "bank_id")
public String bank_id;
@Column(name = "branch_id")
public String branch_id;
@Column(name = "sb_ac_no")
public String sb_ac_no;
@Column(name = "state")
public String state;
@Column(name = "remoteID")
public String remoteID;

public RyotMasterDb() {

}

public RyotMasterDb(String remoteId, String imageData, String ryotNo, String catId, String name, String fatherName, String divId, String secID, String villID, String address, String address1, String add2, String add3, String iiSourceID, String irrType, String totalArea, String suitableArea, String pCode, String disID, String talukID, String firID, String factID, String pontentialRyot, String idProof, String idNo, String mobile1, String mobil2m,String passbook_image, String id_proof_image, String id_proof_back_side_image) {

    this.remoteID = remoteId;
    this.id = Long.getLong(remoteId);

    this.mobile_1 = mobile1;
    this.mobile_2 = mobil2m;
    this.zone_group_id = zoneGroup;
    this.bank_id = bankID;
    this.branch_id = branchID;
    this.sb_ac_no = sbAccNO;
    this.state = state;


}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getMobile_1() {
    return mobile_1;
}

public void setMobile_1(String mobile_1) {
    this.mobile_1 = mobile_1;
}

public String getMobile_2() {
    return mobile_2;
}

public void setMobile_2(String mobile_2) {
    this.mobile_2 = mobile_2;
}

public String getZone_group_id() {
    return zone_group_id;
}

public void setZone_group_id(String zone_group_id) {
    this.zone_group_id = zone_group_id;
}

public String getBank_id() {
    return bank_id;
}

public void setBank_id(String bank_id) {
    this.bank_id = bank_id;
}

public String getBranch_id() {
    return branch_id;
}

public void setBranch_id(String branch_id) {
    this.branch_id = branch_id;
}

public String getSb_ac_no() {
    return sb_ac_no;
}

public void setSb_ac_no(String sb_ac_no) {
    this.sb_ac_no = sb_ac_no;
}
```

}

```
public class AppUtils {

static Fragment mFragment;

public static List<RyotMasterDb> getRyotMasterList() {
    return Select.from(RyotMasterDb.class).fetch();
}
```

}

Comment: `mRyotList` what is its type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a keyListener for your EditText

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                // do your search in here    
                String mobileno=mmobile.getText().toString();
                //search it  
                boolean isInList = checkIsPhoneNumberInList(mRyotList,mobileno);
                Log.i("CheckResult","is my phone number "+mobileno+" in mRyotList: "+isInList);
                if(isInList){
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"your phone number is already registered",Toast.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

for check whether phone which you input in your edittext is in your database by this method

```
private boolean checkIsPhoneNumberInList(List<RyotMasterDb> mRyotList,String phoneNumber){
   if (mRyotList == null || phoneNumber == null) {
       return false;
   }
   boolean isIn = false;
   for (RyotMasterDb rm: mRyotList) {
       if (phoneNumber.equals(rm.getMobile_1())||phoneNumber.equals(rm.getMobile_2())){
           isIn = true;
       }
   }
   return isIn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `AutoCompleteTextView`. An editable text view that shows completion suggestions automatically while the user is typing. The list of suggestions is displayed in a drop down menu from which the user can choose an item to replace the content of the edit box with.

The drop down can be dismissed at any time by pressing the back key or, if no item is selected in the drop down, by pressing the enter/dpad center key.

The list of suggestions is obtained from a data adapter and appears only after a given number of characters defined by [the threshold](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#getThreshold()).

Code Sample:

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
   protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
       super.onCreate(icicle);
       setContentView(R.layout.countries);

       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
       AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
             findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
       textView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }

   private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
       "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
   };
}
```

You can refer to [this example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm) for a detailed explanation.